# Vue composable returns string

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have the following vue composable method:

```js
import {
  ref
} from 'vue';

const useCalculator = (num1: number, num2: number, operation: string) => {
  const result = ref(0);

  switch (operation) {
    case 'add':
      result.value = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case 'sub':
      result.value = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case 'mul':
      result.value = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case 'divide':
      result.value = num1 / num2;
      break;
    default:
      result.value = 0;
  }

  return result;
}
```

When I pass the following params to the function `useCalculator(10,11,"add")`.
I get the following result:
"1011"

Although I've defined the data type for incoming params. The method is returning value by containing them as string

Comment: it is so weird to concat them as string since you pass as number into the func.

But you try explicitly convert them into number beforeadding, `result.value = Number(num1) + Number(num2);`

Comment: @psudo I added an answer, Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any issue in your code, As you are passing the params as a number it should concatenate properly and result should be `21`. Also, As you define the param types in the function definition. It will throw an error during compile time itself if you will pass the `num1` and `num2` as a string instead of number.

Working Demo **:**

```js
const { ref, onMounted } = Vue;

let options = {
  setup: function () {
    const useCalculator = (num1, num2, operation) => {
      const result = ref(0);
      switch (operation) {
        case 'add':
          result.value = num1 + num2;
          break;
        case 'sub':
          result.value = num1 - num2;
          break;
        case 'mul':
          result.value = num1 * num2;
          break;
        case 'divide':
          result.value = num1 / num2;
          break;
        default:
          result.value = 0;
      }
      return result.value;
    }

    onMounted(function () {
      console.log(useCalculator(10, 11, 'add'))
    });
  }
};

let app = Vue
.createApp(options)
.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, do not declare `result` as a `const` if you are going to modify its value later, instead declare it as `var`.

And second, instead of require the type of de variables in the function props. Just convert your inputs to numbers. Example:

```js
var result = ref(0);
      const useCalculator = (num1, num2, operation) => {
      //Here you convert the inputs in floats numbers
        num1 = parseFloat(num1);
        num2 = parseFloat(num2);
        //Here you can also use parseInt() if you just want to have integer numbers

        switch (operation) {
          case "add":
            result.value = num1 + num2;
            break;
          case "sub":
            result.value = num1 - num2;
            break;
          case "mul":
            result.value = num1 * num2;
            break;
          case "divide":
            result.value = num1 / num2;
            break;
          default:
            result.value = 0;
        }
        return result;
      };
```

Comment: ref() returns a Ref object that has a property "value" of type number which you're changing. Using const is perfectly fine, in fact it is a better choice if you're not going to redeclare the variable. Which you aren't doing anywhere in your code.